# How to get the id of a mysql query that doesn't match mine?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql query:

```
$get_friends_posts = "SELECT * FROM users_friendships
                      WHERE userid1 != $myid and userid2 = $myid 
                      or userid2 != $myid and userid1 = $myid";

$friendpost = mysqli_query($mysql, $get_friends_posts);
```

$myid is the unique ID for the user that is logged in and watching this script. Now, I want to get the ID through a check or something that doesn't match mine, like the opponent of the friendship.

In the database there are rows for id, userid1 and userid2.

Comment: your logic is completely wrong, that will not return the result you want

Comment: I know and my brain was about to go off that's why I came here

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return a single column (`userid`) from the `users_friendships` table where `$myid` is either `userid1` or `userid2`. I assume that there would be no rows where `userid1` and `userid2` would be the same value.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN userid1 = $myid THEN userid2 ELSE userid1 END AS userid
FROM users_friendships
WHERE userid1 = $myid OR userid2 = $myid
```

If you want to use these results to get data from another table, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
posts.*
FROM posts
WHERE posts.userid IN
(
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN userid1 = $myid THEN userid2 ELSE userid1 END AS userid
    FROM users_friendships
    WHERE userid1 = $myid OR userid2 = $myid
)
```

Or if you had a more complex need where you needed extra information about the user and also the post, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    users.name,
    posts.date,
    posts.title
FROM users_friendships
INNER JOIN users ON users.userid = CASE WHEN users_friendships.userid1 = $myid THEN users_friendships.userid2 ELSE users_friendships.userid1 END
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.userid = CASE WHEN users_friendships.userid1 = $myid THEN users_friendships.userid2 ELSE users_friendships.userid1 END
WHERE users_friendships.userid1 = $myid OR users_friendships.userid2 = $myid
ORDER BY posts.date DESC
```

Comment: Okay great, that gives me all ID's that I want to have. Another problem: I want to use those ID's in another query now, to give out data from another table that includes the ID's of my friend, right those we get from this now.

Comment: What will your other query do? If, for example, you want to get the name of the other user then you can do an INNER JOIN in the same query to also retrieve the name from another table.

Comment: Like the other table includes datas from posts people make on the site and this is connected to the friends table over the userid. I want to show just the posts that my friends posted.

Logically like SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid = *theIDs I get from the other query*

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how you could query another table (posts) where the userid was returned in the first query (using `IN`). Does that help?

Comment: Thought you might also want to get some info from a users table, so added another query that might help if you need to join multiple tables.

Comment: I don't know if it is a right method but I am getting the information from a users table over another query that I put into the while(){} from the post query

Comment: Maybe best to start a new question and include your relevant code.